# Django redirect URL based on the old URL

Tags: python, django

I have some urls that was originally in the form of uuid:pk when it is referred to specific post, more specifically

```
    path('<slug:slug>/post/<uuid:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

However, I've changed the path to include the post title so that it is more intuitive for the end reader

```
    path('<slug:slug>/post/<slug:post_slug>', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

where post_slug is a contactnation of post.pk and post.title as I have override in the models

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        if not self.post_slug:
            self.post_slug = slugify(str(self.title)+str(self.pk))
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The issue is that i have send some links to some users that contain the old url format. I am wondering how do I redirect them automatically to the new url link.

This is my current post_detail

```
def post_detail(request, slug, post_slug):
    station = get_object_or_404(Station, slug=slug)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, post_slug=post_slug)
    subreddits = station.subreddits.all()
    try:
        post.view_count=post.view_count+1
    except:
        post.view_count=1
    post.save()

    subreddit_for_post=[x for x in post.subreddits.all() if not x.displayed_name == 'all']
    all_posts=subreddit_for_post.posts.all()
    random_post=random.choice(all_posts)
    while random_post==post:
        random_post = random.choice(all_posts)

    reader=request.user
    return render(request, 'Reddit_app/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'reader': reader, 'station': station, 'subreddits':subreddits, 'user_score': user_score, 'random_post': random_post, 'subreddit_for_post': subreddit_for_post})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep both paths in your urls.py, but rename the legacy one so it has a distinct name and calls it own view:

```py
path('<slug:slug>/post/<uuid:pk>/', views.post_detail_legacy, name='post_detail_legacy'),
path('<slug:slug>/post/<slug:post_slug>', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

And then write a new view which redirects users who have the legacy URL to the new URL:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

...

def post_detail_legacy(request, slug, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return redirect('post_detail_legacy', slug=slug, post_slug=post.post_slug)
```

If `Post` objects are large it might be useful to use a more compact query to retrieve the `post_slug`. This code would perform a function similar to `get_object_or_404` except it will only select the `post_slug` column instead of selecting *all* columns.

```py
from django.http import Http404

...

try:
    post_slug = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('post_slug')[:1][0]['post_slug']
except IndexError:
    raise Http404
```